# share href link on twitter from iphone

Tags: iphone

[image]I am implementing href link share on twitter from iphone app.. I am using social sharing framework..
I have used below code for href url..but not able to post href url on twitter
 NSString *ss= @"http://www.w3schools.com/html>Visit our HTML tutorial";
 [twComposer addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ss]];

```
            [twComposer setCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
            [self presentViewController:twComposer animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Can you please help me out

Answer (score 0):

You can post a link to twitter using the following function:

```
- (IBAction)postToTwitter:(id)sender {
    if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter]) {
        SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];

        [controller setTitle:@"Tweet from My Application"];

        NSString *strLink = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" Please refer link http://www.w3schools.com/html Visit our HTML tutorial "];

        [controller setInitialText:strLink];

        [self presentViewController:controller
                           animated:YES completion:nil];

        SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler myBlock = ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result){
            if (result == SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled) {
                NSLog(@"cancel twitter");
            } else {
                NSLog(@"post twitter");
            }
        };
        controller.completionHandler = myBlock;
    }
}
```

See my edited code!!

Hope this helps...
All the best!!!

Comment: Thanks...But i want to share this kind of url  NSString *ss= @"http://www.w3schools.com/html>Visit our HTML tutorial"; [twComposer addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ss]];

Comment: Yes I have checked it...But not working..please check attach screen shot